# Describing all elements in the set algebra generated by given sets in an infinite product

Tags: set-theory

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of probability spaces and define $\displaystyle X=\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i$

Let $A$ be the algebra on $X$ generated by the sets of the form $$\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i \times E_n \times \prod_{i=n+1}^{\infty} X_i, E_n \in P(X_n)$$

Show that every element in $A$ can be written as $$a= \displaystyle \cup_{j=1}^m (\prod_{i=1}^{n_j} E_{j,i}                                                                                                                                 \times \prod_{i=n_j}^{\infty} X_i)$$ where $E_{j,i} \in P(X_i)$ and the union is a disjoint union

Comment: I'm not sure an answer here would benefit the community so much since you have not yet accepted an answer to your previous questions.  Kindly accept some answers if you feel they have helped answer your question.

Comment: sorry i was not aware of the customs of the forum, i will starting accepting answers from now on

Comment: Is this really true?

Comment: He says "algebra", not $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Ahhh. There you go then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this in Paul Halmos' *Measure theory*, Chapter I, §5. He talks about generated *rings* but in your case the distintion is irrelevant---this is the content of one of the exercises in that section, in fact.